# Visual Studio 2015 builds unmodified projects after recent Windows 10 update

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

My Windows 10 has just went through the recent major update, which seems to have somehow upset Visual Studio. It will now fully rebuild all the projects in my VS2015 solutions (C++) even if they aren't modified. Everything was working OK prior to the update. The question is - what could've gone wrong?

I read previous responses to similar problems, looked at the diagnostic build output and tried getting some insight through [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kirillosenkov/2014/08/04/how-to-investigate-rebuilding-in-visual-studio-when-nothing-has-changed/) solution (I don't get any "Project not up to date" output). Nothing really helped me.

Any ideas?

Comment: By any chance, are you using SVN?

Comment: @SG_90, Did the rebuild occur every time when you build your C++ project after Windows 10 update or only occurred for the first build? You can set MSBuild verbosity to either "Detailed" or "Diagnostic" under Tools >> Options >> Projects and Solutions >> Build and Run, this will figure out what was causing a rebuild. Might not help but it's something to try and it's simple.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Yes, this occurs every time, otherwise it wouldn't be a problem :) And like I've written, I've already looked at the Diagnostic output.

Comment: @rrirower I'm using Git.

Comment: Hm, the problem miraculously disappeared today. I still don't know what caused it but I no longer care. Is there any way to close/suspend the question page? I can't submit an answer, since I don't actually have any.

Comment: @SG_90, thanks for your reply. How about the re-build result when you create a new blank C++ project? If this issue not occur, this issue should be related to your project rather than Windows update. For examples you might have circular dependencies, or a resource with "Copy always" property. Or you can rollback your code to the version before windows update, check if it work fine.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT The code did not change between the time when Windows applied the update. Like I said, I experienced no problems before the update. Nothing changed. Anyway, it's a moot discussion now that the problem disappeared by itself.

Comment: @SG_90, OK, Glad to know that this issue not occur. If you get any useful information about this issue, you can share it here. If I get any info about it, I will also post it here, let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Iam suffering from this very same issue. I read somewhere else that playing with the system date may help.